# How to version user-modifiable config JSON file?

Tags: python, json, configuration, pypi

I have multiple JSON files that are packaged together with my [Python PyPI package](https://github.com/TakingItCasual/ec2mc). These JSON files are copied from the source distribution to the .ec2mc/ directory under the user's home directory as configuration files. The top-level configuration JSON file (aws_setup.json) is designed to be modifiable by the user.

How could I set it up so that old configuration versions will be overwritten, unless the user has made their own modifications to the configuration?

My current setup is to add the Version (int) and Protect (bool) keys to aws_setup.json, the Version key being for updating the configuration when the distribution is updated, and the Protect key being for the user preventing the configuration from being overwritten. The logic is the following:

```python
# The config's aws_setup.json must have the "Protect" and "Version" keys
if not all(key in config_aws_setup for key in ("Protect", "Version")):
    cp_aws_setup_to_config(aws_setup_src_dir)
# If the "Protect" key has been set to True, prevent overwriting aws_setup
elif config_aws_setup["Protect"]:
    pass
# Version can be set to 0 during development for constant refreshing
elif source_aws_setup["Version"] == 0:
    cp_aws_setup_to_config(aws_setup_src_dir)
# Update if aws_setup_src has larger version number
elif source_aws_setup["Version"] > config_aws_setup["Version"]:
    cp_aws_setup_to_config(aws_setup_src_dir)
```

The cp_aws_setup_to_config function overwrites the configuration with the distribution's version:

```
def cp_aws_setup_to_config(aws_setup_src_dir):
    if os.path.isdir(config.AWS_SETUP_DIR):
        shutil.rmtree(config.AWS_SETUP_DIR)
    shutil.copytree(aws_setup_src_dir, config.AWS_SETUP_DIR)
```

While it works, I feel this setup is a bit convoluted, and would like suggestions for a simpler way of achieving the same effect.

Comment: What if you try to calculate a sha1 hash of the JSON to see if it's been modified?

Comment: I tried using filecmp.cmpfiles(). It works, so I don't need the Version tag anymore. Do you have suggestions for better methods of indicating that a user has made modifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution's template configuration and the user's configuration can be compared with file comparison, given that they both exist on the same system simultaneously. filecmp's cmpfiles is ideal for this, as it can compare files within similar directory structures.

```
def recursive_cmpfiles(src_dir, dest_dir):
    """wrapper for filecmp.cmpfiles, which recursively finds src_dir's files"""
    prefix_len = len(src_dir.parts)
    cmp_files = []
    for path, _, files in os.walk(src_dir):
        for f in files:
            cmp_files.append(Path(*(Path(path) / f).parts[prefix_len:]))
    return filecmp.cmpfiles(src_dir, dest_dir, cmp_files, shallow=False)

# If 'Modified' key is True, prevent overwriting config's aws_setup
if config_aws_setup['Modified'] is False:
    diffs = os2.recursive_cmpfiles(aws_setup_dir_src, aws_setup_dir_dest)
    # If source and dest aws_setup differ, overwrite dest aws_setup
    # If dest aws_setup missing files, overwrite dest aws_setup
    if diffs[1] or diffs[2]:
        cp_aws_setup_to_config(aws_setup_dir_src)
```

This eliminates the need for the Version key, although the 'Protect' (now 'Modified') key is still used.